# How to determine topic of given document (text)?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, classification, weka

I know how to classify texts through Weka, I can insert a folder of texts in Weka GUI and trying different algorithms it can show me if one of the texts is positive/negative to some topic.

Now I need something different, I want to build an application that when the user inserts a single-text file, to tell the topic of the text.

Is there any possibility to do this by Weka? If anyone would give me a hint I will be very pleased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "topic"? It is a very broad concept, but in most cases it is simply the finite set of possible text categories like "science", "sport" etc. which you can call `C`, and treat as a supervised classification problem just as you would do with "positive/negative" classification. There is nothing special about classyfing into multiple categories. Yet you still would need a training set for each category.

To sum up - you can use WEKA in exact same fashion as for binary classification, just perform classification with more labels (if your categories are mutualy exclusive, ie. none of the texts is about both "science" and "sport") or create `|C|` binary classifiers if your text can be the part of any subset of the categories (which is more reasonable, as documents are often "in between" some topics) and simply answer with the set of categories that your corresponding classifiers answered "yes" (positive).

If you would like to do this in unsupervised way (without training set) then it would be much more complex task requiring actually modelling topics by some kind of text summarization/topic modeling techniques, which as far as I know are not implemented in WEKA. In fact to my best knowledge this approach is not mature enough to talk about any "good" solutions - these are rather research fields with many approaches and mixed results.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use Weka? If not, there are other good text classification systems with open/free access for topic categorisation. I'd recommend trying [Open Calais](http://www.opencalais.com/) which can be downloaded or used a web service.